# Locking an array of std::mutex using a std::lock_guard array

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, raii

I have the following array of mutexes:

```
std::mutex mtx[5];
```

And I would like to lock them all with an RAII style:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> grd[5] { mtx[0], mtx[1], mtx[2], mtx[3], mtx[4] };
```

While the above code works, it isn't ideal as I can't write it independently of the size of the array (here 5).

Is there a way to do that? Shall I work with template magic to create an `std::initializer_list` out of an array? (is that possible?)

I'm open to using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays, I used those here for conciseness. Ideally this works in C++14 but any solution up to latest standards is fine.

Comment: Can you clarify in what kind of an application this kind of mutexes are needed, specifically an array of mutexes (you can't have a vector of mutexes, C++ does not work this way)? It seems a bit strange, can you give an example of what kind of locking requirements this approach solves? Maybe there's a better way to do it. Just want to make sure that this isn't some senseless puzzle that comes from one of those many kinds of spam sites that promise to turn anyone into a C++ uberhacker, simply by solving their puzzles (I don't want to waste my time if that's the case).

Comment: I'm a bit curious about which compiler and C++ version you are using. I can't get `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> grd[5] { mtx[0], mtx[1], mtx[2], mtx[3], mtx[4] };` to compile in g++, clang++ or MSVC.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My real situation is actually unrelated to mutex, I have a resource acquisition class which acquire the resource at construction and release it at destruction and take as constructor argument a reference to the owner of the resource. I used std::mutex and std::lock_guard because they have the same RAII design.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry, it seems the needed constructor calls are marked explicit and therefore won't work unless I manually add std::lock_guard on each argument. I'm actually using a custom RAII data-structure and mine have that constructor non-explicit so it is working fine. Somebody below was mentioning std::scoped_lock but they too have explicit constructor...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock).  It takes N mutexes and locks them on creation and unlocks on destruction.  That would give you

```
std::scoped_lock sl{mtx[0], mtx[1], mtx[2], mtx[3], mtx[4]};
```

If that's still too verbose you can wrap that in a factory function like

```
// function that actually creates the lock
template<typename Mutexes, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
auto make_scoped_lock(Mutexes (&mutexes)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::scoped_lock{mutexes[Is]...};
}

// helper function so you don't have to create your own index_sequence
template<typename Mutexes, std::size_t N>
auto make_scoped_lock(Mutexes (&mutexes)[N])
{
    return make_scoped_lock(mutexes, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx[5];
    auto lock = make_scoped_lock(mtx);
}
```

---

If you switch to using a `std::array` to hold the mutexes then the code can be simplified to a call to `std::apply` to do the expansion of the array into a parameter pack like

```
template<typename Mutexes>
auto make_scoped_lock(Mutexes& mutexes)
{
    return std::apply([](auto&... mutexes) { return std::scoped_lock{mutexes...}; }, 
                      mutexes);
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::mutex, 5> mtx;
    auto sl = make_scoped_lock(mtx);
}
```

Comment: @paolo Good idea.  I forgot the `std::array` works with `std::apply`.  I've added that version to the answer as well.  Thanks.

Comment: @paolo The `std::apply` in `std::array` is exactly what I needed. Could you make a separate answer for that which I could accept?

Comment: @Nonyme Presumably, paolo made the comment under Nathans answer as a suggestion to add that to the existing answer, which Nathan also did.